# Is there a relationship between $\|X\|_2 ^2$ and $(\sum_i x[i])^2$?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Is there a known relationship between $\|X\|_2 ^2$  and $(\sum_i x[i])^2$, where $X$ is a vector in the real space, $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the 2-norm, and $\sum_i x[i]$  is the sum over the elements of the vector $X$.

Comment: Are you assuming 1-norm, 2-norm or …?

Comment: And what do you mean by $\sum X$?

Comment: I just improved the description.

Comment: Yes, there is a relation.  If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then

$ \displaystyle 0 \le ( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i )^2 \le n \| x \|^2 $

To prove this, note that

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \mathbf{1}^T x $

where $\mathbf{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{1} = [1, 1, \dots, 1]^T $.

Hence,

$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 = x^T {\mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}}^T x $ 

It easy to show that the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix ${\mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}}^T $ are $\lambda_{Min} = 0 $ and $\lambda_{Max} = n $.  From the properties of quadratic forms, the inequality given above follows.

Comment: In general $\frac1n \sum x_i^2 \ge  \left( \frac1n \sum x_i \right)^2$ as their difference is $\frac1n \sum (x_i-\bar x)^2$. So    $n \sum x_i^2 \ge  \left( \sum x_i \right)^2$ with difference $n \sum (x_i-\bar x)^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cauchy's inequality (later generalized by Buniakovski and by Schwarz,
see [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)) says
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i\right)^2 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2\right)
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|^2\right) .
$$
If we take $y_i=1$ for all $i$, we obtain
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 \le n\;\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2
= n \|X\|_2^2 .
$$

---

Just for fun, let me add: Buniakovski's inequality
$$
\left(\int_a^b f(t)g(t)\;dt\right)^2 
\le \left(\int_a^b |f(t)|^2\;dt\right)
\left(\int_a^b |g(t)|^2\;dt\right)
$$
Schwarz's indquality: if $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is an inner product, then
$$
\langle\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\rangle \le \|\mathbf x\|\;\|\mathbf y\| ,
$$
where the norm $\|\mathbf x\|$ is defined as $\langle \mathbf x, \mathbf x\rangle^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a relation.  If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then

$ \displaystyle 0 \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2 \le n \| x \|^2 $

To prove this, note that

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \mathbf{1}^T x $

where $\mathbf{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{1} = [1, 1, \dots, 1]^T $.

Hence,

$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 = x^T {\mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}}^T x $

It easy to show that the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix ${\mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}}^T $ are $\lambda_{Min} = 0 $ and $\lambda_{Max} = n $.  From the properties of quadratic forms, the inequality given above follows.

Comment: This is also a straight consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality.

Comment: Yes.  You're right, I totally missed that.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume 2-Norm (i.e.: $\|X\|_2^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2$), your vector $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and if by $\sum X$ you mean $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$, then the following relation seems to be the only natural one I can think of:
$$
\left(\sum X\right)\cdot \left(\sum X\right) = (X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n) \cdot (X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n) = X_1^2 + X_2^2 + \ldots + X_n^2 + X_1 X_2 + \ldots + X_{n-1}X_n = \|X\|_2^2 + \sum\limits_{i \neq j}X_iX_j,~\text{where }i,j\in \underline{n}
$$